# The wifi-menu command doesn't show any networks?

Tags: arch-linux, wifi

I recently installed Black Arch Linux and am using `wifi-menu` to attempt to connect to wifi. I have tried this before on other computers and it worked fine. Here's what the output looks like:

```
[ blackarch ~ ]# wifi-menu
Scanning for networks... failed
No networks found.
```

Again this has worked before without a problem. Any fixes?

Answer (score 0):

You’ll probably need to do a bit of digging to make that work.

General WiFi troubleshooting on Linux looks roughly like this:

1. check if the WiFi device shows up.

   ifconfig -a # should show you your network devices.

If no WiFi devices, then you need to figure out why not: is the driver loaded, is there a hot key on the device that disables the WiFi, is there a setting in the BIOS that disables it, is there even a Linux driver for the WiFi chipset.

2. if the wireless device shows up in ifconfig, is the device listed as up?  If not, toggle it up.  If it is, toggle it down and then up.

Those are the common things to look at, each with its own potentially complicated troubleshooting routines.  Good luck!